# OpenGL - Rendering sorted vs fragmented VBO

Tags: performance, opengl, vertex-buffer

I am rendering an old game format and the world is broken into small regions. The region vertices are sorted by texture index. All of the vertices are added into a huge VBO. I also use an IBO which is created every frame has grouped texture indices so that I can render each texture in one call.

My question lies with the way the vertices are stored, sent, and rendered. In some levels, there are thousands of regions so if I am rendering the a texture that is common in every region, it could be 1000 fragmented "sections" of the vertex buffer separated by other texture vertices.

I have been thinking it might be good to sort the arrays too but it will require a lot of code rewrite so I am interested in the theory behind any performance increases.

1. Does having to rendering from so many different parts of the VBO cause issues?
2. Are there are performance increases in my case with sorting the VBO?
3. I know glDrawRangeElements can improve by sending the beginning and end and some graphics card optimize with this? Are there any benchmarks on the speed difference?

Comment: I think you should optimize towards one single draw call. A texture array or a texture atlas is required then but it wouldn't get any faster.

Comment: @dari I have read extensively about these and it doesn't seem like I can still have an array or atlas with mipmapping. Regardless, I am still curious as to the direct question.

Comment: You can have mipmapping with both a 2D texture array and a texture atlas. Since you will be drawing the same amount of data either way, the overhead of OpenGL calls may make a difference if your vertex stage is not the bottleneck. In this case, as dari said, you should focus on limiting the number of drawcalls. That being said, using mipmapping with texture arrays or atlasses is very easy and should speed up your drawing a lot, so try that one first.

Comment: Well, using mitmapping with array textures is totally unproblematic. Using it with atlasses can be a bit more tricky, if the different texture parts don't nicely fit into pow-of-two-sized cells in the atlas.